# Kendo slider no initial value

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-slider

I'm trying to initialize a kendo-slider but I want to load it **without a preselected value**.

Currently, I initialize the slider by adding an extra step at the beginning (`minValue - 1`), so the drag handle starts at this position (label: '-').

Is there a better idea without having to add an extra value at the beginning?

```js
const thisSlider = $elem.kendoSlider({
  increaseButtonTitle: 'Up',
  decreaseButtonTitle: 'Down',
  min: minValue - 1, // Add an extra step at the beginning
  max: maxValue,
  smallStep: 1,
  largeStep: 1,
  value: null,
})

// Change the label to '-'
thisSlider.siblings('.k-slider-items').find('.k-first').find('.k-label').html('-')
```

Comment: Perhaps hide the drag handle until some other condition is met, at which point you show it? Should be fairly simple with a bit of jQuery to modify the CSS.